# Configuring ReplicaSet using Chef and mongo ruby gem

Tags: ruby, mongodb, chef-infra

I am trying to setup `replicaset` using `Chef` and `Mongo` Ruby gem. I have already got `Chef` cookbooks from supermarket but the problem is that they used old version of Mongo gem and its related objects.

I mean, Please help on how to use `replicaset` commands with examples available [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/2.4.2/Mongo/Cluster/Topology/ReplicaSet).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I run this code 'ReplicaSet.new(['127.0.0.1:27017', '127.0.0.1:27018', '127.0.0.1:27019'])' in irb, it shows error like "NameError (uninitialized constant ReplicaSet)"

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the `sc-mongodb` cookbook already, check out https://github.com/sous-chefs/mongodb#replicasets in the documentation but the short version is to use the `sc-mongodb::replicaset` recipe instead of `::default`.

Comment: I am using this cookbook only. The problem is objects used in this are not supported in new version of mongo gem. Ex: mongo::connect is used in sc-mongodb cookbook, but it is not supported in new version of mongo gem. mongo::client is used in new version to connect mongodb database.

Comment: Please help me on how to use new objects in mongo gem 2.5.0